# Can we use SharePoint 2010 with Virtual PC in 32-bit Operting System?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

i want to install SharePoint 2010 in my system.but my system is 32-bit where SharePoint 2010 is 64-bit.So can we use Virtual PC to use SharePoint 2010 in my System.is it Possible ?

Please tell me how can i use SharePoint 2010 in my 32-bit System?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

SharePoint 2010 is not available in 32 bits. You need a 64 bits system (Windows Server 2008 or Windows Vista / 7).

Virtual Server can not virtualise 64 bits system, so you need to switch to HyperV (require Windows Server), VMWare or Virtual Box (can be used on client OS).

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 is 64-bit only.  New for developers in 2010, you can run it on a 64-bit windows desktop.  I am running SP2010 on my Windows 7 development pc and it works great.

SharePoint 2010 is supported on x64-bit Vista (SP1 or SP2) and x64-bit Windows 7.
Here is the setup/configuration link on MSDN.  [Dev Environment Setup - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869(office.14).aspx)

The desktop/developer setup is a bit painful.  It took me about 90 minutes to get it fully working including downloading and installing hotfixes and required components.